# Convert list from epoch to human readable time

Tags: python, time, epoch

Good morning guys,
I have a list in Python which contains some epoch times. I'd like to convert every epoch time in human readable time. I would normally use this code but I don't know how to use it in a list:

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',   time.localtime(1483947846/1000.0))
```

My list in Python is:

```
myList = [ '1483947846',  '1417947246', '1417327000']
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function:

```
def epoch2human(epoch):
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', 
        time.localtime(int(epoch)/1000.0))
```

or a `lambda`

```
epoch2human = lambda epoch: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(int(epoch)/1000.0))
```

and use something like this:

```
humanTimes = [epoch2human(t) for t in myList]
```